# How can I convert a long function into a Biginteger into a string?

Tags: java, type-conversion, long-integer, biginteger

I'm trying to change my `long` variables into `BigInteger` because I'm storing numbers of the fibonacci series in it and then ultimately turn them into a  string. Here is my original code.

```
public class Fib {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        long n1=0,n2=1,n3,i,count = 100;
        System.out.print(n1+" "+n2);//printing 0 and 1

        for(i=2;i<count;++i)//loop starts from 2 because 0 and 1 are already printed
             {
                n3=n1+n2;
                System.out.print(" "+n3);
                n1=n2;
                n2=n3;
            }

        }} :
```

and I've tried to convert it into a BigInteger AND a string afterwards like this...

```
public class Fib {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        long n1=0,n2=1,n3,i,count = 100;
        BigInteger n1,n2,n3,i,count = BigInteger.valueOf(n1,n2,n3,i,count)
        System.out.print(n1+" "+n2);//printing 0 and 1

        for(i=2;i<count;++i)//loop starts from 2 because 0 and 1 are already printed
             {
                String n3= n1+n2;
                System.out.print(" "+n3);
                n1=n2;
                n2=n3;
            }

        }}
```

However, an error occurs. I've tried to read the syntax for converting long variables into BigIntegers and BigIntegers into strings and I understand that what I've done is wrong.

However, I can't seem to figure out the right way to implement what I want to do, which is why I've came to StackOverflow to seek help.

If anyone can help me with this, It would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain what the line `BigInteger n1,n2,n3,i,count = BigInteger.valueOf(n1,n2,n3,i,count)` is intended to do?

Comment: `an error occurs` - compiler exactly telling you what's wrong, and you should pay attention to it. Copy the error-message to the question.

Comment: I'm trying to convert it into a BigInteger from a long using this. I found information on this site https://simplesolution.dev/java-convert-long-to-biginteger/#:~:text=To%20convert%20a%20given%20long,from%20a%20given%20long%20value.  which says the way to do it is 'BigInteger value = BigInteger.valueOf(longValue)'

Comment: Do you think it's a valid Java? Did you try to have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html)? It fairly easy to find out that the version of `BigInteger.valueOf()` that you're trying to use doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

The java spec defines rigidly what operators can be applied to what and what it means. Specifically, all the usual mathy operators (`+`, `-`, etc) all apply **only to primitive numbers**, with the one exception being `+` which can show up between strings and anything else too, but then it's a completely different thing (string concatenation instead of numeric addition).

**They cannot be applied to BigInteger AT ALL** - the spec simply doesn't list what that would mean, and java does not have operator overloading.

The direct replacements are methods confusingly named `add`, `subtract`, `multiply`, `divide`. So,

```
BigInteger a = BigInteger.ONE;
BigInteger b = BigInteger.ONE;
BigInteger c = a + b; // wrong
BigInteger c = a.add(b); // correct
```

The better names would have been `plus`, `minus`, `times`, and `dividedBy`. In the sense that if I write on a blackboard `a = b + c`, and I ask you to read it out loud, you'd say: "a equals b plus c". Not "a equals b add c". But, it is what it is - just remember, `a.add(b)` will calculate the sum of a and b and return a brand new `BigInteger` with the result. It does *not* add `b` to `a`. (BigInteger is immutable; it is not possible to change its value by calling methods on it, or any other way outside of hackery).

Answer (score 0):

First, You will need to change the following line because you can't do multiple instantiations at the same time, and the method provided only allows for one argument to be passed.

Change

```
BigInteger n1,n2,n3,i,count = BigInteger.valueOf(n1,n2,n3,i,count);
```

to

```
BigInteger n1    = BigInteger.valueOf(lngN1);
BigInteger n2    = BigInteger.valueOf(lngN2);
BigInteger n3    = BigInteger.valueOf(lngN3);
BigInteger i     = BigInteger.valueOf(lngI);
BigInteger count = BigInteger.valueOf(lngCount);
```

and notice how I also changed the variable names for the longs. You can't declare a variable name twice in the same scope.

You cannot do this:

```
long       n1 = 1L;
BigInteger n1 = BigInteger.ONE;
```

because they have the same name. Which n1 are you refering to? So, your longs need to have different names than your BigIntegers.

Really, you don't need all those variables/properties to be BigInteger. When I clean up the code I get this:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Fib {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long count = 100;
        BigInteger n1 = BigInteger.valueOf(0L);
        BigInteger n2 = BigInteger.valueOf(1L);
        BigInteger n3 = null;
        
        
        System.out.print(n1 + " " + n2);//printing 0 and 1
        
        for (long i=2; i<count; ++i) {//loop starts from 2 because 0 and 1 are already printed
            n3 = n1.add(n2);
            System.out.print(" " + n3);
            n1 = n2;
            n2 = n3;
        }       
    }
}
```

(EDIT/ADDITION)
And actually, BigInteger has ZERO and ONE already built into it, so you can just do

```
BigInteger n1 = BigInteger.ZERO;
BigInteger n2 = BigInteger.ONE;
```